# Wordpress generating image sizes not set in media or theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my Settings -> Media I have the following settings:

- Thumbnail: 512x0, crop thumbnail unchecked
- Medium: 512x0
- Large: 1024x0

No other plugins enabled. When I upload a 2560×1920 pixels image, I would expect 3 files to exist, a 512,1024, and original 2560 wide image. However I also get a 768, 1536, 2048, and -scaled (which is the same dimensions as the original). I have a custom theme that doesn't add any image sizes, and while I could understand the 2048 as the retina version of the 1024 image, the 768 and 1536 ones are a mystery to me.

Even when I set 0 for thumbnail, medium, and large in the media settings I still get a 768, 1536, 2048 and -scaled version generated when I upload an image.

Is there any way to prevent WordPress from generating these extra images that I don't want?

#### EDIT

I set all the media settings to 0 and added

```
remove_image_size('1536x1536');
remove_image_size('2048x2048');
add_filter( 'big_image_size_threshold', '__return_false' );
```

to a function in `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'myfunction')`

That gets rid of the 1536 and 2048 transforms (despite the fact that the transformed images have heights other than 1536 and 2048 but oh well), as well as the `-scaled` one. However even if I add `remove_image_size('2048x2048');` WP still generates a 768 wide transform along with keeping the original.

How can I get rid of that last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes', '__return_empty_array', 999 );
```

Does the trick. For some reason, the 768 wide image transform is the `medium_large` preset that you cannot remove with `remove_image_size('medium_large');` like the rest.